# Calculate time spent by users on app using Google BigQuery Firebase analytics data

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I am trying to calculate total time spent by users on my app. We have integrated firebase analytics data in BigQuery. Can I use sum to the values of engagement_time_msec in select statement of my query? This is what I am trying :

```
SELECT SUM(x.value.int_value)
FROM "[dataset]",
UNNEST(event_params) AS x WHERE x.key = "engagement_time_msec"
```

I am getting very big values after executing this query. I am not sure if is it ok to use SUM("engagement_time_msec") for calculating total time spent by users on app.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Define what's a big value? Since it's milliseconds, I expect big numbers.

Comment: It is 6426000000 ms which equals to 1785 hours. i am not sure if this is the right way to calculate time spent on app.

Comment: A month has 720 hours, that would be 2 users spending all their days in the site. Or 4 users spending half their days. Or 8 users doing 6 hours each day. Yeah, I'm not sure either if this is the right way, but if we knew your ~number of users we could judge quickly if it's too big.

Comment: Well we don't have much users and also it is an booking app. I am not expecting that users are spending this much time on the app. Well there can be another factors too but can you please verify my query above. Is it right way to calculate, this is what i want to know at this stage.

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge to answer that question in a precise way at this time :/. But I would look into the data - does it ever reset to 0, or does it keep increasing per user? If it's an ever increasing number, then get MAX() per user/session instead.

Comment: Thanks for your time @FelipeHoffa

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what dataset you have. Ideally, you would want login and logout timestamps if you have. Take the time_diff between the values, grouping by user, device, loadsequence etc. Anything which defines a single event